# Consulta muy lenta

Tags: base-de-datos

Intento sacar de una base de datos id_propietarios que sus eventos hayan tenido mas de 1500 ventas en un rango de fecha y que no tengan gestor

```
SELECT
    COUNT(v.id), v.id_propietario
FROM
    ventas v
    INNER JOIN propietarios p ON p.id = v.id_propietario
    INNER JOIN usuarios_permisos up ON up.id_propietario= p.id
    INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id = up.id_usuario
WHERE
    v.fecha_compra >= '2022/03/08 00:00:00'
    AND u.gestor = 0
GROUP BY v.id_propietario
HAVING COUNT(v.id) > 1500
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema? ¿qué depuraciones has hecho? ¿de qué SGBD estamos hablando: MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc? Pulsa en [edit]  para completar la pregunta agregando la etiqueta del SGBD específico.

Comment: Es cosa mia o la tabla `usuarios_permisos` es innecesaria en esta búsqueda? En el join de usuarios podrías simplemente indicar `u.id = p.id` en vez de `up.id_usuario`.

Comment: @Benito-B al menos por el nombre `usuarios_permisos` parece ser una tabla asociativa para gestionar una relación *muchos a muchos* entre las entidades `usuario` y `permiso`. No obstante, la entidad `permiso` no aparece en la consulta y OP no da demasiadas explicaciones. Quizá me equivoque, pero es lo que interpreto por el nombre de la tabla. A veces se le da poca importancia, pero la *convención de nombre* es importante, porque ayuda bastante a entender el código. La consulta de OP no tiene sentido, porque estaría uniendo tablas que no tienen nada que ver, al menos nominalmente.

Answer (score -3):

La velocidad o la lentitud es relativa. Para una consulta 3sg. puede ser lento, y en cambio para otra puede ser rápido.

En principio la consulta no parece tener nada "extraño", aunque la velocidad no sólo depende de la consulta.

Lo más fácil sería evaluar el plan de ejecución y ver si en algún punto hay un "cuello de botella".
Tendrás que revisar:

1. **claves primarias** de las tablas (suponemos que las tienen).
2. **Índices sobre las claves foráneas** (imaginemos que los tienen).
3. **claves foráneas** (imaginemos que las tienes).
4. **otros índices** (si son necesarios) sobre campos de filtro.

Comment: "culo de botella" o "cuello de botella"? :-)

Comment: *En principio la consulta no parece tener nada "extraño"*, pues me parece que esto `INNER JOIN usuarios_permisos up ON up.id_propietario= p.id` es MUY EXTRAÑO, lo es, al menos desde la lógica o desde la *convención de nombre*, porque intenta unir dos tablas que no parecen tener relación. Si la tabla se llama `usuarios_permisos` se supone que es para relacionar las entidades `usuario` y `permiso`, no `usuario`  y `propietario`.

Comment: Tienes razón @masterguru, se me mezclaron dos expresiones...  ;-D

Comment: @A.Cedano; Cuando me refería a "extraño" me refería a la construcción de la consulta. Que los nombres sean o no los más adecuados no afecta a la velocidad. Hemos de suponer que la relación es correcta (sino apaga y vámonos). Tampoco se puede asegurar que el nombre sea "incorrecto" sin ver el resto de la estructura y sin saber dónde más se usa esa tabla.

Comment: Tal como mencioné en el comentario de la pregunta, la tabla `usuarios_permisos` no tiene sentido, puesto que ni siquiera la está usando en la propia consulta... el único sitio donde la usa podría reemplazarse perfectamente por `p.id` y todo funcionaría igual. Puestos a agilizar una consulta, lo normal sería empezar quitando un `inner join` innecesario, que si es lo que parece, y es una tabla pivote, eso estará haciendo crecer la consulta de manera exponencial sin necesidad alguna.

Comment: Esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta.. no?

Comment: En respuesta a @Benito-B. No puedo entender cómo dices que un `INNER JOIN` es innecesario sin saber los datos que contiene la tabla. Está claro que dependiendo del `Id_propietario` de la venta y de los valores que existan en la tabla `usuarios_permisos` aparecerán o no determinados registros (se tendrán en cuenta en el `Count`). Si quitas ese `INNER JOIN` dependiendo la los datos existentes, saldrán más o menos regitros en el `SELECT`.